# Does Client Lib/SDK reach out for OCR?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

Sorry for the dumb question, for the following sample code below, does it reach out to the real Azure Cloud for OCR process or just perform it locally?

```
const { FormRecognizerClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/ai-form-recognizer"); // v3.2
const fs = require("fs");

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(MyLocalFile);

const client = new FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));
const poller = await client.beginRecognizeInvoices(readStream, {
 onProgress: (state) => {
   console.log(`status: ${state.status}`);
 }
});

const [invoice] = await poller.pollUntilDone();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Form Recognizer SDK and it will call the Analyze Invoice API on the cloud hosted service to analyze the document.